# Comparing strings trouble with gson parsed JSON data

Tags: java, json, gson

```
void setMaxNumPassengers() {
    for (Options option : options) {

        String carType = option.getCarType();

        if(carType.indexOf("STANDARD") > 0 || carType.indexOf("EXECUTIVE") > 0 || carType.indexOf("LUXERY") > 0) {
                maxNumPassengers = 4;
        }
        else if(carType.indexOf("PEOPLE_CARRIER") > 0 || carType.indexOf("LUXERY_PEOPLE_CARRIER") > 0) {
            maxNumPassengers = 6;
        }
        else {
            maxNumPassengers = 16;
        }
    }

}
```

I've used gson to store my JSON file data into variables in my Options class, but now I'm trying to compare the string of car_type with other strings and it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried making my car_type variable a JSONElement and then using getAsString() but it doesn't seem to work either. My output comes back as always 16 or for some reason 6, and I'm not sure why. Any other details could be provided but I have quite a few classes.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misspell `LUXURY`? (This is one reason why "magic constants" inline are discouraged.) Note also that `LUXURY_PEOPLE_CARRIER` already contains `PEOPLE_CARRIER`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `indexOf` rather than `contains`?

Comment: I think the use of `.indexOf() > 0` is wrong, you might instead want to use carType.includes("XYZ"). Also, the structure of `if(something){ ...} else if (something else) {...} else if....` is called a christmas tree which while sometimes necessary, in general, should be avoided. a switch() statement might work better. Also, you might want to consider enum usage instead of keeping type as a string.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was expecting different values of the same variable I'd stored in my class. What I should be doing is storing the maxNum variable in my Options class and adding a setter() method which stores the maxNum differently for each car type. Thanks for your help boys.